# How to hide Edit Property option from the Edit Control Block of Document Library Items

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I would like to hide the Edit property option form ECB of ducument Library items in SP2010 or capture the click and redirect to my own aspx page. Is it possible? Please help

Thanks
aYus

Answer (score 0):

Customizing Edit Control Block is not possible using Custom Action. Couple of ways you can get your requirement done.

1. Option 1 : Use custom Javascript and get this solved.
2. Option 2 : Use SharePoint Designer or Object Model code & change the Default Edit Form URL, change the Edit form to point to page of your choice.

You can refer these links to get more information on how to achive it using Javascripts

1. [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397/dynamically-display-edit-control-block-menu-item-in-sharepoint)
2. [Link2](http://mossytips.blogspot.com/2008/07/hiding-item-level-menu-from-edit.html)
3. [Link3](http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/SharePoint-Hiding-Menu-Items-from-the-Edit-Control-Block.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Kusek. I have a couple of questions.
- IS there a way I could find out which aspx page the users redirect to when they click the Edit Property of document library items?  
- If I would choose to modify core.js, which section in this js file? Thanks again aYus